# How to do depth-first traversal in neo4j without the traversal framework?

Tags: neo4j

How to do depth-first traversal in neo4j without the traversal framework.I'm not using an embedded neo4j database.

Answer (score 0):

[Cypher variable-length expansions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength) should be using dfs by default (bfs should only be used when using `shortestPath()`.

Otherwise, use [APOC path expanders](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) ([apoc.path.expandConfig()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_with_config)) with `bfs:false` in the config map.